# NLog singleton to Castle Windsor

Tags: castle-windsor, ioc-container, nlog

I have problem with CastleWindsor Installer. Now I have class for Nlog logger.

```
public class Log
{
    public static Logger Instance = LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();
}
```

And I want trasform this to  castle, but I can not figure out how to create IWindsorInstaller for this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the [Castle Logging Facility](http://docs.castleproject.org/Default.aspx?Page=Logging-Facility&NS=Windsor) together with Castle NLog integration (both available from nuget). Then you can inject the interface Castle.Core.Logging.ILogger into your objects. You wouldn't use the actual NLog ILogger but the abstraction from Castle Windsor.

i don't have access to my git repo in the office right now to check, but that should be the line to add to your WindsorInstaller:

```
container.AddFacility<LoggingFacility>(f => f.LogUsing(LoggerImplementation.NLog).WithConfig("nlog.config"));
```